# Is it possible to use a C++ smart pointers together with C's malloc?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, smart-pointers

Some of my code still uses `malloc` instead of `new`. The reason is because I am afraid to use `new` because it throws exception, rather than returning `NULL`, which I can easily check for. Wrapping every call to `new` in a `try{}catch(){}` also doesn't look that good. Whereas when using `malloc` I can just do `if (!new_mem) { /* handle error */ }`.

Therefore I have a question. Can I use smart pointers together with `malloc`?

Something like:

```
SmartPointer<Type> smarty = malloc(sizeof(Type));
```

Something like this.

Is this possible?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: If you want new to now throw an exception and just return NULL you can use: Type* bla = new (std::nothrow) Type();. I think it's better to use std::nothrow than malloc since the later doesn't call the constructor.

Comment: What are you going to do in the error handling code to compensate for not getting memory? Usually the test is if the alloc worked then do work. If it failed exit with an error code (which is a compilcated way passing control back up the stack).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you are using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, you can specify a custom deleter.  For example,

```
struct free_delete
{
    void operator()(void* x) { free(x); }
};
```

This can be used with `shared_ptr` like so:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp((int*)malloc(sizeof(int)), free_delete());
```

If you are using `unique_ptr`, the deleter is a part of the `unique_ptr`'s type, so the deleter needs to be specified as a template argument:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, free_delete> up((int*)malloc(sizeof(int)));
```

However, it is better to use exceptions correctly, rather than avoiding them, when writing C++, especially with respect to allocation failures.  In most cases, you cannot successfully recover from an allocation failure in the function trying to do the allocation, so exceptions can help you to handle the error where you are actually capable of handling it.

Comment: You can also pass `free` directly: `auto myPointer = std::unique_ptr<int, void (*)(void*)>(..., free)`

Comment: @PatrickChilton Note that if you do this, your `unique_ptr` will be twice as large.

Answer (score 13):

You can use nothrow keyword with the new operator, which will return NULL rather that throw an exception. For details see link below:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/nothrow/

Comment: Is using `nothrow` a common practice? (Because I haven't actually seen personally use of nothrow in real practice myself.)

Comment: It is the most common way to use `new` when you don't want it to throw an exception. But no, it is more common to just use `new` and work *with* exception handling. If allocation fails, you can't usually do much about it anyway, so letting an exception propagate is a pretty clean way to exit gracefully.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to use `new (std::nothrow) Type`. This will act just like `new Type`, but will give null rather than throwing if it fails. This will be much easier than trying to make `malloc` behave like `new`.

If you really must use `malloc`, then remember to construct and destruct the object correctly:

```
void* memory = malloc(sizeof(Type));
Type* object = new (memory) Type;
object->~Type();
free(object); // or free(memory)
```

You can use this with a some smart pointers by giving it a custom deleter:

```
void malloc_deleter(Type* object)
{
    object->~Type();
    free(object);
}

if (void* memory = malloc(sizeof(Type)))
{
    Type* object = new (memory) Type;
    std::shared_ptr<Type> ptr(object, malloc_deleter);
    DoStuff(ptr);
}
```

But this would be much simpler using non-throwing new:

```
if (Type* object = new (std::nothrow) Type)
{        
    std::shared_ptr<Type> ptr(object);
    DoStuff(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Using malloc has the additional advantage of letting you use realloc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33706568/1858225

Answer (score 2):

What code goes in `/* handle error */`? Is there anything you can actually DO with an out-of-memory error? I just let the application terminate with a call stack (core dump) so I have an idea at least one possible place that might be causing problems.

Using `malloc` to allocate memory for C++ classes and objects is not a good idea because it won't make sure that the constructors are called, possibly leaving you with uninitialized classes that may even crash if they have virtual methods.

Just use `new` and `delete` and don't worry about catching the exception, after all running out of memory IS an exceptional case and should not happen in normal runs of the application.

Comment: There are some situations in which you _can_ handle the error. For example, memory-greeding numerical computations (ex. simulations) can easily get out of memory on weak machines, but in this case you can stop right away and display an error instead of crashing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the SmartPointer does on destruction.  If you can specify `free` as a deallocator, that could work.  For example, boost::shared_ptr allows you to specify a deleter.

I didn't pay enough attention to your reason for wanting this.  I agree with the other answers that using the nothrow `new` is a much better idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use malloc with smart pointers (you have to cast return value to target pointer type, though and provide custom deallocator). But better option is to use `nothrow` version of `new` operator.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/nothrow/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try "placement new". See [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new)

Answer (score 1):

Use [nothrow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/nothrow/).

> **Nothrow constant**
>
> This constant value is used as an
>   argument for operator new and operator
>   new[] to indicate that these functions
>   shall not throw an exception on
>   failure, but return a null pointer
>   instead.

```
char* p = new (nothrow) char [1048576];
if (p==NULL) cout << "Failed!\n";
else {
    cout << "Success!\n";
    delete[] p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a question.

What happens if "Type" is a type whose constructor can throw? In that case, one still needs to handle exceptions in a try/catch block.

So is it a good idea to abandon exception based approach?

I would say that one can use the Abstract Factory/Factory Method design pattern and have all the 'new's in relatively lesser set of files/namespaces/classes, rather than these being scattered all around the place. That may also help in restricting the use of try/catch block to a relatively lesser code.

Answer (score 1):

for oneliner:
`unique_ptr<char, void (*)(void*)> buffer( (char*)malloc(size), free );`