# increase array with char* [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, char

I'm dealing with dynamic arrays in C++. Help with the following code.

I'm trying to read the characters one by one and make the C-string. If the array size is not enough, I increase it. But the function increaseArray works with an error and returns a string with other characters. What I am wrong?

```
void increaseArray(char* str, int &size){
    char* newStr = new char[size * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        newStr[i] = str[i];
    }
    size *= 2;
    delete[] str;
    str = newStr;
}

char* getline()
{
    int size = 8;
    char* str = new char[size];
    char c;
    int index = 0;
    while (c = getchar()) {
        if (index == size) increaseArray(str, size);
        if (c == '\n') {
            str[index] = '\0';
            break;
        };
        str[index] = c;
        index++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This "  str = newStr;" sets the local variable str to newStr. That local variable is immediately discarded. You want a pointer-to-pointer or a reference.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string` or even `std::vector<char>` ??

Comment: _"I'm trying to read the characters one by one and make the C-string. If the array size is not enough, I increase it"_ Literally what `std::string` is for. Why don't you use it and save yourself the trouble? Your code would not pass review in my team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `increaseArray` you are assigning `newStr` to `str` however `str` is local copy of pointer in `increaseArray` function thus change is not visible outside it.

Simplest fix is to change `increaseArray` signature to:

`void increaseArray(char*& str, int &size)`

So reference to pointer will be passed, thus changes to `str` inside `increaseArray` will be visible outside it.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. A little confused with pointers and references.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that. 
Its simple..

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void increaseArray(char* &str, int size){
     str = (char *)realloc(str,size*2);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help much as you ignored the pointer returned by `realloc`.

Comment: @ForceBru I forgot that. I already made the necessary changes to that.

Comment: Actually, since the OP used `new[]` to allocate his memory, he cannot use `realloc` according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33706568/4717805)