# Using Smart Pointers in Cython for Dynamically Allocated Arrays

Tags: arrays, memory, cython, smart-pointers

I am writing a Python wrapper for a function call with the signature

`double** foo(double** arrayIn, int dim1, int dim2);`

and need to build `arrayIn` inside my Python wrapper. One possible solution for this is given [here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/3dbwy9/cython_2d_memoryview_to_c_pointer_error/) However, since Cython includes support for smart pointers, I would prefer to implement that solution. One way to do this would be [a combination of malloc and a unique_ptr with a custom deleter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477525/is-it-possible-to-use-a-c-smart-pointers-together-with-cs-malloc) Another (simpler) solution would be to use [the allocator class from libcpp.](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/memory.pxd)

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libcpp.memory cimport unique_ptr, allocator

def testArray(int dim1, int dim2):
    cdef allocator[double *] ptr_al
    cdef unique_ptr[double *] myptr
    cdef np.ndarray arr
    cdef double[:,:] carr

    myptr.reset(ptr_al.allocate(dim1))
    arr = np.ndarray((dim1,dim2),dtype=np.float64,order='C')
    carr = arr

    myptr.get()[0] = &carr[0,0]
    myptr.get()[1] = &carr[1,0]
    myptr.get()[2] = &carr[2,0]
```

This code compiles and executes correctly (with Cython 24.1, Python 3.5, VS2015). My concern is whether or not everything will be properly deallocated / garbage collected. My understanding is that Python is responsible for the `ndarray`, and `unique_ptr` should be responsible for the `double *[]` created by `allocator`. Is this correct, or will the code create a memory leak? Is there a way I could verify that everything has been properly deallocated?

Comment: It should be noted that the allocate solution will corrupt the heap for arrays larger than 511 entries. I've created an issue for this (https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1592). I have been able to implement the first smart pointer solution without any problems.

Comment: Re: bug report: Switching to Py2.7 might help, if it's an option for you (I bet its support is more mature) - I tried this on Linux/GCC/Py2.7/Cy25.2 and it runs without issues for all kinds of dim1.

Comment: I tested on Linux/GCC4.8.4/Py3.5.2/Cy24.1 and it ran without issue for me as well. Maybe this is a windows thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this correct, or will the code create a memory leak?

I don't think this should leak.

> Is there a way I could verify that everything has been properly deallocated?

You can call `testArray` in a loop and see if the process memory is growing linearly or stays about constant. Since you know `dim1` and `dim2`, you can estimate the memory leak size if something isn't freed properly.

There are other ways to test for memory leaks, in more complicated situations: there are debug versions of the C library that will tell you if you've deallocated all of the memory you allocated. Also, there are tools like `valgrind`, and `clang`'s `leaksanitizer`, but in your case I'd go with the loop.

Comment: I ran the loop 100 times creating a series of 100 x 100 array of doubles and the process memory remained approximately constant. Looks like it is a clean solution.