# Exception-aware malloc version of make_unique

Tags: c++11, exception, malloc, unique-ptr, placement-new

In `C++11` there is no `make_unique` (can't use `C++14`), although one can quickly be mocked up like so (plenty of answers already out there suggest something like this):

```
template< typename T, typename ... Args >
std::unique_ptr< T > my_make_unique (Args && ... args) {
  return { new T( std::forward< Args >( args )... ) };
}
```

This is fine if the desired result is for `new` / `delete` to be invoked on `typename T`. In my case it's not because I'm overriding global `new` / `delete`, which internally will (where convenient) use `unique_ptr`. So instead I'm using `malloc` and various wrappers & allocators based on `malloc` to make STL containers work without extra bloat at the site of usage. I was doing fine with this approach until exceptions came along...

Building on the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477525/is-it-possible-to-use-a-c-smart-pointers-together-with-cs-malloc) so far I have this as a possible generic solution:

```
template< typename T >
struct destroy_free {
  void operator() (void * p) {
    if ( !p ) return;
    static_cast< T* >( p )->~T();
    free( p );
  }
};
template< typename T, typename ... Args >
auto malloc_make_unique (Args && ... args) -> std::unique_ptr< T, destroy_free< T > > {
  if ( auto ptr = malloc( sizeof(T) ) )
    return { new ( ptr ) T( std::forward< Args >( args )... ) };
  return { nullptr }; // global new would throw bad_alloc here.
}
```

This seems ok but exception handling is totally ignored here with regard to how `new (ptr) T(...)` would work, as opposed to `new T(...)`, and how this affects any version of `make_unique` especially when using a custom allocation method.

For a start, I'm aware throwing `std::bad_alloc` is ill advised, however I believe the principle of least surprise applies here and it's forgivable to emulate what `new` would do (ie, throw when allocation fails as opposed to returning `nullptr`). This begs two questions.

**1. Is it justifiable to replace `return { nullptr }` with `throw std::bad_alloc()`?**

**2. To correctly replicate `new T(...)`'s behavior, if the constructor throws then the exception needs to be caught, so the memory can be released immediately and *then* rethrow the constructor exception?**

Assuming yes to both, is the below handling the situation correctly or is there anything else to consider?

```
template< typename T, typename ... Args >
auto malloc_make_unique_v2 (Args && ... args) -> std::unique_ptr< T, destroy_free< T > > {
  if ( auto ptr = malloc( sizeof(T) ) ) try {
    return { new ( ptr ) T( std::forward< Args >( args )... ) };
  } catch( ... ) { // catch constructor exceptions
    // assumed: memory allocated but object not constructed
    free( ptr ); // release memory, object was not constructed?
    throw; // propagate whatever the exception was during construction?
  }
  throw std::bad_alloc(); // no memory allocated, throw bad_alloc?
}
```

edit - please note I'm ignoring alignment for simplicity.

Comment: It is a design decision whether your function throws or returns `nullptr` on error.   But the notion of throwing on some errors and returning `nullptr` for others - which your first version does - will confuse/annoy users of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assuming yes to both, is the below handling the situation correctly or is there anything else to consider?

Looks ok to me.

There is [std::allocate_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) which creates shared_ptr with object memory allocated by custom allocator. What you are making is essentially `allocate_unique` which does not exist (perhaps, yet) in standard c++. Maybe you could create custom allocator that uses malloc/free and then implement your own [make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (if you don't have it) and `allocate_unique`.