# Dynamic allocation of a character array (Smart Pointers)

Tags: arrays, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm trying to dynamically allocate a character array in c++ using smart pointers based on the user input like

```
std::cout<<"Input a word: ";
std::cin>>std::unique_ptr<char[]>ch_array(new char[]);
```

So when the user inputs the string it only consumes the necessary amount of bytes. Since it keeps giving me an error is there any other workaround to achieve such results ?

Comment: What is the use-case for something like that? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why can't you use a `std::string`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have to create an array using smart pointer take an input and check if it's a palindrome or not (It's an assignment). My mentor said I can use static array but I just don't want to do it because user can give any amount of characters.

Comment: std::string does all you need. If your instructor doesn't allow you to use std::string, you need to implement what std::string does yourself. There is nothing magical in it: it reads characters one by one until a delimiter is found, and reallocates storage when it becomes too small to store the next character. So you need to know how to do both of these things.

Comment: @n.m. But can't we just create a array using smart pointers based on string ? Like when we initialize something like--> char array[]="Hello world!" and it automatically initializes array based on the given string.

Comment: You can of course. It would be totally pointless though. If you are allowed to use std::string, just use it throughout.

Comment: `char array[] = "some string"` initializes the array to a fixed specific size, the length of the string plus the terminator. It's the compiler that handles that at the time of compilation, not at run-time.  Like I said in my answer, arrays must have a known size, no matter if it's allocated dynamically with `new[]` or statically by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

A few of the problems:

- You can not have an array of unknown size, you must always create one with a size.
- You can not declare or define variables in all contexts, like part of a generic expression.
- A `std::unique_ptr` object is still a `std::unique_ptr` object, there's no built-in conversion operator to convert to the type being pointed to, which means it can't be directly used as a destination for the formatted input operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use std::string or any other standard containers, as if was suggested earlier, you have basically two choices:

**Straight forward one** - allocate buffer in advance, big enough to store the input

```
std::cout << "Input a word: ";
char ch_array[100];
std::cin >> ch_array;
```

**Much complicated one** - read the input by symbol and reallocate the memory

Of Cause the reallocation casts a lot. And I do not suggest to use it, until the memory is extremely limited resource and you cannot spend even an extra byte of data. Just to show how complicated it can be:

```
char* ch_array;
static int count = 0;
char c = getchar();

while(c != '\n')
{
    if( count == 0)
        ch_array = static_cast<char*>( malloc( sizeof(char)+1 ) );
    else
        ch_array = static_cast<char*>( realloc(ch_array, sizeof(char)*(count+2) ) );

    ch_array[count] = c;

    count++;
    c = getchar();
}
ch_array[count] = '\0';
```

In this code error checks are also skipped which are absolutely necessary for the reallocation. With them, it will be even more complicated

As for ***the smart pointer***, which is in the title, but seems unrelated to the question:

With the first option you can allocate the buffer on heap and use it:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> ch_array(new char[100]);
```

With the second you need a custom deleter, as described here [Is it possible to use a C++ smart pointers together with C's malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477525/is-it-possible-to-use-a-c-smart-pointers-together-with-cs-malloc)